# What is the difference between is used to doing something and usually do something?

Tags: word-usage

for instance, has it the same meaning to say :

I am used to playing football.

and

I usually play football.

Answer (score 3):

The first has to do with familiarity and the second has to do with frequency (or personal preference).

"I am used to playing football" means that you know how to play football, you have played it before and you feel comfortable playing it.

"I usually play football" means that it is your habit to play football (i.e. you play it often) or that you normally choose to play football in preference to some other sport.